# Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, если есть и слово "это", и вводное слово

Tags: тире, сказуемые, подлежащее

Политическая деятельность — это деятельность в сфере политических, властных отношений. Политические отношения, в свою очередь, — это отношения между субъектами политсистемы по вопросам завоевания, осуществления, удержания власти.

Интересует тире во втором предложении. С одной стороны, здесь есть вводное слово между подлеж. и сказ., тогда тире не нужно, с другой - есть "это", значит тире ставится.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тире нужно ставить.

> Если в составе сказуемого есть указательные слова ЭТО, ВОТ или ЗНАЧИТ, тире надо ставить перед ними **всегда** ([Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_172))

Я так понимаю, что всегда значит всегда, и наличие вводного слова это правило не отменяет.

**Политические отношения, в свою очередь, — это отношения между субъектами политсистемы по вопросам завоевания, осуществления, удержания власти.**